# Looping and control flow

Tags: c#, loops

Thanks in advance for your help. I'm not a programmer or student asking for homework help, just a technician helping out with work projects.

This one should be easy, but I've brain-farted and I need your help. I've written a GUI control program in C#, but I'll write examples in semi-pseudocode for clarity. I have two boolean control variables and List of void doSomething() methods.

```
bool ready = true;
bool willLoop = true;

runButton.Click(...) { ...
```

willLoop is set true/false by a toggle button. I want runButton.Click(...) to iterate through the List of doSomethings(), each of which set ready to false and then back to true when they have finished executing. When ready is set back to true, the next Item in the list will execute and set ready to false and back to true when it is finished. If willLoop is true then the program should iterate though the List over and over again, executing each item. If somebody presses the toggle button and sets willLoop to true or false while the program is executing, I need the program to finish iterating through the list and then either stop(break?) if willLoop is false after the last Item is executed, or iterate again if willLoop is true. All the threading/realtime stuff is handled automatically, I just need a (nested?) looping structure that will use the control variables to do what I need.

I'm only interested in the looping/iterating portion of the code so pseudocode will be fine. The real-world application is controlling an external device with a serial port - each item in the list is a method which sends a command to the device and sets ready to false. When the device finishes moving, it sends a string back and that listener sets ready back to true.

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Your description makes it sound like the doSomething()s start a thread and then returns immediately, before that thread completes. Is this true? If not there is no reason to toggle ready, as each doSomething() should block until it has completed and then you can just run the next one.

Answer (score 0):

the structure you need is something like

```
runButton.Click(...) {
  ready = true
  while (willLoop)
    for each item in list
      ready = false
      process item
      wait until (ready == true)
}
```

I'm not practical with C# but I guess that `Click` callback is no asynchronous so as soon as you click the button everything will stop and you won't be able toggle it again. Did you already take care of manage such multithreading issues?

Comment: Thanks for your swift answer. I realized that I wasn't clear with my question so I added some detail. Basically, if willLoop is set to false after the last Item in the List executes, I need to stop. If willLoop is set to true, I need the program to iterate again. All threading and realtime stuff is handled automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my though on the matter :

```
public partial class MyFormClass : Form
{
    private bool ready = true;
    private object readyLock = new object();
    private bool willLoop = true;
    List<Action> myFunctionList = new List<Action>();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Queue<Action> remainingActions = new Queue<Action>();

        do
        {
            remainingActions = new Queue<Action>(myFunctionList);
            while (remainingActions.Count > 0)
            {
                lock (readyLock)
                {
                    // In case someone was already in the while,
                    // but took the last item in the queue.
                    if (remainingActions.Count == 0) break;

                    ready = false;
                    Action currentAction = remainingActions.Dequeue();
                    currentAction();
                    ready = true;
                }
            }
        } while (willLoop);
    }
}
```

You'll understand that you can substitute "myFunctionList" by whatever mean you want your function list to be stored.